# excel simple if then else in excel 2007

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

i m sure its an easy task but i dont know how to do it, and i was wondering if anyone can help me...

imagine in excel 2007 i have a row that is full of lets say 1000 lines,,, its cell on these lines has a value in greek language that is
**Άρρεν**  that is male
 or 
**Θήλυ**   that is female

i want to measure from cell B2 till cell B1000 how many (sum) **Άρρεν** i have and how many **Θήλυ**

its a simple if then else with counters... how can i do that?? many ways i know but i want the easiest.. :(

as always thank you in advance guys...

Comment: You can try =COUNTIF(...) [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:B1000,"Άρρεν")
=COUNTIF(B2:B1000,"Θήλυ")
```

Comment: No problem @dc03kks. A vote up would be nice though ;)